# Knee: dull pain after the game

Tags: knee-pain

Saturday I was on soccer training, during a shot on goal from left leg I felt slight unpleasant sensation in left knee (right side of the knee). And it's all, but three hours after the game dull pain in the same left knee began. Already two days have passed, but the pain still remains. The same dull,unpleasant and pulsating, but not very strong. I can bend knee ok and can walk.

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

Have it checked by a knee specialist.  Could be a meniscus tear.

Comment: Could be any number of things. The question, however, is off topic as it is asking for medical diagnosis/advice.